# Use of spark pipe in a spark streaming application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, couchbase, hadoop-yarn

**Setting the scene**
I have a spark streaming application written in scala.
Inside this application I need to [pipe](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/pipe-in-spark/) data to a python script.

**How I do it now**
In the driver main class:

```
ssc
   .couchbaseStream(from = FromBeginning, to = ToInfinity)
   .flatMap(...)
   .flatMap(...)
   .flatMap(...)
   .transform(x => functionName(x))
   .flatMap(...)
   .map(...)
   .saveToCouchbase(bucketName, StoreMode.UPSERT)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

inside functionName (x from above is of type RDD stored in variable rdd):

```
val pipeRDD = rdd.pipe(scriptPath)
```

**The Question**
I am not sure if this is a good way to do it.
My concern is that there will be a large overhead in executing the python script for every x.
But since it is a streaming application, I don't see how I can do it differently.

What is the best way to use pipe in a Spark streaming application?
How would you do it and why?

Comment: Why not rewrite the Python in Scala or use PySpark?

Comment: It is an advanced machine learning script that uses a lot of python specific dependencies that are not available in Scala. And the Spark application (in Scala) is also advanced and uses some of the Spark features that are not available in the PySpark API. It works fine with pipe though, but I am thinking that there must be a better way to use pipe in a spark streaming application than the way I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll work fine... It's like Hadoop Streaming for Spark - nothing is "wrong" there, and if you're limited by availability functions, you don't have much options.

The only downside is that `scriptPath` file must be the available  across all executors or the script (and its dependencies) need to be shipped alongside the Spark application JAR file to all executors in the cluster via `--files` or `--archives` flags

By the way,

```
transform(x => functionName(x))
```

Is the same as

```
 transform(functionName)
```